# Restricting unchecking checkboxes after n are unchecked - Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

I want to restrict user to uncheck check-boxes if minimum three are unchecked. He would not be able to uncheck anymore check-boxes if any three are already unchecked.

Here is the code.

http://jsbin.com/corecetepa/1/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like

```
<input ng-change="!option.selected && permissions.headers | filter: {selected: true}).length<=3 && option.selected= true" type="checkbox" 
ng-model="option.selected" 
ng-checked="option.selected"/> 
{{  option.title  }}
```

**OR**

You could move the same logic to controller method.

**Markup**

```
ng-change="changeCheckbox(option)
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.changeCheckbox  = function (option)
{
    if(!option.selected && $scope.$eval('permissions.headers | filter: {selected: true}).length<=3'))
       option.selected = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this,

```
<label ng-repeat="option in permissions.headers"> 
      <input ng-click="checkPermission()" type="checkbox" 
      ng-model="option.selected" 
      ng-checked="option.selected"> 
      {{  option.title  }}
    </label>

  $scope.checkPermission=function(option){
      var lengthTemp=($filter('filter')($scope.permissions.headers,{'selected':true})).length;
       if(lengthTemp<3) {         
            option.selected=!option.selected;
       }     
    };
}
```

**$filter('filter')($scope.permissions.headers,{'selected':true})).length** will filter those options in permissions.headers for which checkbox is selected.

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for this but this will disable the check-boxes to be checked . I want them to be checked but not unchecked when the limit is reached.

Comment: Check the edited answer and let me know if this is what you were looking for. @NishantSankhala